# Modeling the difference between DC and AC current in a superconducting coil

Tags: electric-circuits, experimental-physics, electromagnetic-induction, superconductivity

I have an application I'm trying to model that involves using superconducting coils to produce a steerable dipole. To some degree, the problem is easier if I can modulate the current through the coil, but I have read in a few places that there can be practical challenges related to the superconducting coils being "perfect inductors." Can someone help me get a better understanding of how to mathematically model a superconducting coil in both a DC and AC circuit? Specifically, I'd be curious if trying to vary the current quickly produces operational challenges like excess heat which makes it more difficult to keep the coil in a superconducting state. Thanks!